# How i can open HTML page in my Native application?

Tags: iphone

i an new in this Field.I want to open static HTML page which i have so how can i open that page in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

NSString *htmlTemplateLink = [bundle pathForResource:@"infopage" ofType:@"html"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlTemplateLink]];

wview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
wview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[wview loadRequest:request];
wview.delegate=self;

//wview.multipleTouchEnabled=YES;
wview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

[self.view addSubview:wview];
```

Answer (score 0):

See [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and its [`-loadRequest:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadRequest:) method.

Comment: Sure, search Google for "uiwebview example".